# Cannot create Small Caps Selector on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, ios12

This code below enabled me to create small caps text on iOS 12. However on iOS 13 it's stopped working.

iOS 12 log

```
.SFUIDisplay-Semibold
.SFUIDisplay-Semibold
```

iOS 13 log

```
.SFUI-Semibold
TimesNewRomanPSMT
```

It seems that the SFUI font has changed name at least in iOS 13, but has it also dropped support for small caps?

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
print(font.fontName)

let settings = [[UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier: kLowerCaseType,
                 UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier: kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector]]

let attributes: [UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName: AnyObject] = [UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.featureSettings: settings as AnyObject,
                                                               UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.name: font.fontName as AnyObject]

let smallCapsFont = UIFont(descriptor: UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: attributes), size: 20)
print(smallCapsFont.fontName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was always wrong. You start by creating a font and then you derive a font descriptor from it by passing through the font's *name*:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
let settings = [
    [UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier: kLowerCaseType,
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier: kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector]
]
let attributes: [UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName: AnyObject] = [
    UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.featureSettings: settings as AnyObject,
    UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.name: font.fontName as AnyObject // ** NO!
]
let smallCapsFont = UIFont(descriptor: UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: attributes), size: 20)
```

That was *never* correct. You should derive the font descriptor directly from the *font itself*. This is what your code should *always* have looked like. It worked in iOS 12 and it works now:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
let settings = [
    [UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier: kLowerCaseType,
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier: kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector]
]
let desc = font.fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([.featureSettings:settings])
let smallCapsFont = UIFont(descriptor: desc, size: 0)
```

Comment: I was struggling with this with almost identical code, and after testing with yours I noticed I had `.featureIdentifier` and `.typeIdentifier` mixed up. Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas They are terrible names! I have a bug filed on that.

Comment: Nice to know I'm not alone. You wouldn't happen to know how to exclude digits from the effects of small caps? (Q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65041221/220820)

Comment: @Andreas You would just have to use a different "font" (i.e. a different variant).

Answer (score 2):

System fonts like this are now longer reference-able with 'dot' / `.` notation (even when recreating them like your `font.fontName` example) as per:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/

Starting with iOS 13, you can utilise the new enum `UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign`, using `regular`, `rounded`, `serif` or `monospaced`.

An example of how to create font using descriptors in Swift (see how I'm using the `design` parameter):

```
extension UIFont {

    convenience init?(
        style: UIFont.TextStyle,
        weight: UIFont.Weight = .regular,
        design: UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign = .default) {

        guard let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: style)
            .addingAttributes([UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.traits: [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.weight: weight]])
            .withDesign(design) else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(descriptor: descriptor, size: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from @Ash Camerons answer, here is the updated code that allows you to apply small caps

Note, this only works in iOS 13+, but you could optionally add the `.withDesign(systemDesign)` line for iOS 13 and above.

```
let pointSize: CGFloat = 20
let weight: UIFont.Weight = .semibold
let systemDesign: UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign = .default

let settings = [[UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier: kLowerCaseType,
                 UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier: kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector]]

let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .callout)
        .addingAttributes([UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.traits: [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.weight: weight]])
        .addingAttributes([UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.featureSettings: settings])
        .addingAttributes([UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.size: pointSize])
        .withDesign(systemDesign)

let font = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor!, size: pointSize)
```